# MySQL insert query work on sql managers but not from within php code

Tags: wamp

Im using WampServer and when i run this query:

```
insert into users (pname,puname,email,psw,Addr,Gps,Mob,Ass,About,Pic,Prev,Want,Pt,Rate,Dat) 
   values ("aaa","admin","a@a.a","a","a","33.3216452,44.35840350000001","11111111111",
           "","","img/icon.png",0,0,0,0,"2014-01-15 08:04:32");
```

from phpmyadmin it works good but when i run it from browser (php code) i got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"aaa","admin","a@a.a","a","a",' at line 1

and when i run it from ems manager it say "Query OK, 1 rows affected" but no row added

Comment: put all values in single quote. it will solve your prob.

Comment: yataaaaaa, its work, thx